# opencv and hydro

Tags: ros-hydro, opencv2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been trying to run opencv on hydro but none of the tutorials work .. I have checked and my camera is working but output not shown in ros ... help pls
Thanks in advance
And kindly provide lonk to learn about ros with opencv for hydro !
EDIT1

i have found dat i don't have a camera driver for ROS ...... can u recommend 1 dat works on ROS hydro .... Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/133671/opencv-and-hydro/) by [deepak.shankar94](https://answers.ros.org/users/11771/deepak.shankar94/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-02-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2014-02-26**:
Can you edit your question and include exactly what code/commands you're using, what you expect to happen, and what is actually happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Basically, in ROS it uses the cv_bridge for convert into image, and the opencv is the same as the normal opencv library ( maybe Opencv 2.4.6), you can use this link for the reference.
http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages

---

Originally posted by [domikilo](https://answers.ros.org/users/8836/domikilo/) with karma: 89 on 2014-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0